# Get error [Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inServiceProvider] when renaming Dimension attribute in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence

I got an error when I renamed a Dimension's attribute in the SSAS.

I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (Version 12.0.21005.1 REL). The SSAS service is running on SQL Server 12. I **didn't** get the error when I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL).

The screenshots of the process is shown below:

1, the original name is [State Province Name]

[image]
[image]

2, I tried to rename it to [State-Provice]

[image]

3, I got the error. The rename doesn't work in the Attributes pane. However, it works in the Properties pane.

[image]
[image]

4, I tried to rename again. This time I didn't get the error and the name changed in the Attributes pane this time.

[image]

The whole stack is shown below:

```
===================================

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inServiceProvider (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.ARDiagramDataProvider.ListNode..ctor(DimensionAttribute attribute, IGraphModify g, ISelection inSelection, IServiceProvider inServiceProvider, IValidationInfoProvider inValidationInfoProvider)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.ARDiagramDataProvider.InitGraphStructure(IEnumerable`1 attributes)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.ARDiagramDataProvider.RefreshUIContents(IList`1 changesList)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.BaseChangeTrackerEx.RefreshUIContents()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ChangeTracker.OnRefreshUIContentsAndSelection()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ChangeTracker.RefreshUIAppropriately()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ChangeTracker.transactionService_TransactionClosed(Object sender, ScopeTransactionCloseEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.ComponentModel.ScopeTransactionCloseEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ScopeTransactionCloseEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.ComponentModel.ScopeTransactionService.OnTransactionClosed(ScopeTransaction transaction, Boolean transactionCommitted)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.ComponentModel.ScopeTransaction.OnCommit()
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerTransaction.Commit()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DimensionBuilder.SetComponentName(INamedComponent inamedComponent, String strNewName)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DimensionBuilder.RenameAttribute(DimensionAttribute attr, String name)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DimensionBuilder.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.IDimensionTreeViewDataProvider.SetAttribute(Int32 nAttr, String strAttr)
```